# Is solr4 capable of cross-core join with multi-conditions

Tags: join, solr

solr4 introduced join feature, so we can use the url below:

```
 {!join from=fromField to=toField fromIndex=fromCoreName}news_headline:apple
```

but i have such a scenario, not only news_headline is needed, but also the news_type, how can i add news_type in this url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good sleep, i realized this url is the same as q, so we can solve it like this:

```
{!join from=fromField to=toField fromIndex=fromCoreName}news_headline:apple AND news_type:internal
```